# In callback function with Javascript closure, how to access the global variable

Tags: javascript, html, closures

It is simple:
I need to register an event property with a function. But in order to pass arguments to the function, I create a closure.

```
var x=0

function foo(bar1,bar2){
    return function (){
        alert (bar1+bar2);
        x++;   
    }   
}

for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].onclick=foo(x,i)
}
```

Since I have 5 `div` elements, and I thought it should alert like this if I click all the div from top to down:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

but instead it output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

It seems like that every time in `foo(x,i)`, `x` is equal to `0`. How do I get `foo()` to access the new value of `x` instead of its first initiation?

Comment: You're incrementing `x` but not using it in the addition in the function. JavaScript always passes by value, so when you did  `foo(x,i);` it made a copy of the value `0`. If you want the handler to use the current state of `x`, then don't pass `x` to `foo()`. Just pass `i`, and inside the handler do `alert(x + bar1);`. [*jsFiddle DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/5JSZt/)

Comment: @cookiemonster You should have posted that as an answer.  I didn't see your comment and now my answer is basically the same as your comment.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: That's alright. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `x` only within the inner function.  This function is only called once an element is clicked.  As a result, at the time `foo` is called, `x` is always 0.  It is only incremented later when something is clicked and at that point the values of `bar1` are already set (to 0).

You could do something like this instead:

```
var x=0

function foo(bar1){
    return function (){
        alert (bar1+x);
        x++;   
    }   
}

for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].onclick=foo(i)
}
```

In this way you will always use the **current** value of `x` instead of the value at the time `foo` was called.

Comment: you should try running your code in a jsfiddle before you answer a question.

Comment: Can I let the x increment before returning the inner function?

Comment: lol in your code, try clicking the same div more than once, and see if that don't mess up everything... It works just fine if you click one at a time.

Comment: @user3448456 When you increment all depends on when you want `x` to increase.  If you want it to increase every time something is clicked, then the code in my answer is correct.  If you want `x` to be locked in as `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. then you can use your previous code but increment `x` before calling `foo`.

Comment: @JayHarris All depends how you interpret the intent of the original code.

Comment: That's true but this interpretation is not very consistent in a practical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `x` where you increment `i`. Because on every iteration `x` is still zero thus the values you're getting `0,1,2,3,4` are actually the values of `i`.

In your code, you are passing the value 0 to the variable `bar1` on every iteration and the only time that `x` increments is after you click the button not during the iteration, so if you put another alert for x in front of this alert `alert (bar1+bar2);` you see what i mean.

Finally to increase `x` on every iteration you must explicitly do it in the loop. like this:

```
;i++, x++)
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N6B9M/)

This would output `0,2,4,6,8` without increment x on every click.

```
    var x   = 0,
        div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    function foo(b1, b2){
        return function () {
          alert (b1 + b2);
        }            
    }

    for (var i = 0; i< div.length; i++, x++) {
        div[i].onclick = foo(x, i);
    }
```